# How to use a webpart to present a filtered document library in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part

I'm attempting to present a document library that is filtered either by title or tags. Is there a good way to do this via a web part?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a ListView WebPart and then change the View to Filter by Title or Tags